# What are polynomial coefficients?

Tags: analysis

A linear differential equation with algebraic coefficients is of the form $$\sum a_i f^{(i)}=0$$ with $a_i$ being algebraic, ie. for every $i$ $a_i$ is a zero of a polynomial with rational coefficients.

But what is a linear differential equation with polynomial coeffizients, ie. what does is mean that $a_i$ is polynomial?

Comment: Where did you encounter these statements. Context is essential in properly interpreting them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A differential equation with polynomial coefficients is just an equation of that form where the $a_i$ are polynomials, not necessarily numbers. There is no such thing as a polynomial number.

Comment: Thank you! Polynomials of what?

Comment: For instance, $xf'(x) = 3$ is a differential equation with polynomial coefficients. The coefficient $x$ is a polynomial.

Comment: Is 'polynomial coefficients' a stronger condition than algebraic coefficients?

Comment: @user114179 No. It's just a different condition.